# How to use sympy.latex and sympy.sympify to produce unevaluated parameterized expression fr'\frac{{3}}{{{i}}}'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

How to use `sympy.latex()` and `sympy.sympify()` to produce unevaluated parameterized  expression `fr'\frac{{3}}{{{i}}}'`?

```py
from IPython.display import display,  Math
import sympy as sym
for i in range(-1,2):
    display(Math(fr'\frac{{3}}{{{i}}}'))
for i in range(-1,2):
    display(Math(sym.latex(sym.sympify(f'3/{i}'))))
```

[image]

#### Edit

The objective is to generate:

```py
fr'\frac{{3}}{{{-1}}}'
fr'\frac{{3}}{{{0}}}'
fr'\frac{{3}}{{{1}}}'
```

with `sympy.latex()` and `sympy.sympify()` (or its variant).

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `evaluate=False` into `sympify`:

```py
for i in range(-1,2):
    display(Math(sym.latex(sym.sympify(f'3/{i}', evaluate=False))))
```